# lua 5.3 + luasocket 3.0rc1-2: undefined symbol: luaL_setfuncs

Tags: nginx, lua, luasocket, luarocks

I have Luasocket 3.0rc1-2 installed through luarocks with Lua 5.3 running on the server.

When I run a script requiring luasocket on nginx (1.8.0) with LuaJIT (2.1), it produces an error message:

```
lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so':
    /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: luaL_setfuncs
```

On the luasocket github page, I see `Out of the box support for Lua 5.3.`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luajit is not lua 5.3. You cannot mix runtimes.

You have a version of luasocket built for lua 5.3 but you are running luajit 2.1.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll downgrade back to 5.1.  Thanks!